# Tricks with transforming function plots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I want to try a function graph trick and need some advice.

We have a function graph like this:

[image]

The trick is as follows:
We take an arbitrary interval $x∈[a;b]$ and the corresponding section of the function graph $f$. Further, we must introduce a new function F, such that for $t_0=0$ its value is equal $Y=y_a$, and for $t_k = b$ its value is equal $Y=y_b$. This can be graphically displayed as follows.

[image]

Sorry for the messy design. I was in a hurry. Can such a trick be done?

Comment: $y_a$ and $y_b$ don't really make sense. Are they supposed to be $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, given the interval $[a,b]$? Because if so, they are the wrong way around in the picture.

Comment: @SenZen, Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, the only thing you need is a linear parametrization mapping $$t=0 \mapsto b \mbox{ and } t=b \mapsto a $$
$$\Rightarrow x(t) = a + \frac{b-a}{b}(b-t)$$

As you can see: $x(0) = b$ and $x(b) = a$

So, plugging this into your function $f$ gives your desired function

$$F(t) = f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{b}(b-t)\right) \text{ on } [0,b]$$

**Additional info after comment:**

In order to "freeze" the maximum for $b>0$ and using an analytic expression you can do the following:

Assuming that $F(b) = f(a)$ is the (allowed) maximum you can do the following:

$$H(t) = \frac{F(t) + F(b)}{2} - \frac{|F(t) - F(b)|}{2} \text{ on } [0,+\infty)$$

This cuts off $F$ at $F(b)$ and continues with $F(b)$ for $t>b$, provided that $F$ would otherwise continue above the given threshold.

Comment: Yes, this is more like the truth. And tell me how to "freeze" the value of the function if t> b? Without a piecewise linear function?

Comment: @dtn It depends on what you mean by "fix". Usually one would define the remaining part of the function graph piecewise as constant functions outside the interesting interval.

Comment: I need to "freeze" the maximum of a function without using a piecewise representation.

Comment: Here is a desmos link of your case ...
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4dgvbcwi0l

Comment: If t is only about the maximum i can give you a representation using some absolute values ... just a minute

Comment: Thank you, your solution suits me.

Comment: you are welcome. happy to be able to help :-)

Comment: Just seen, in your case you need actually the minimum provided that the function $F$ would stay above the desired threshold for $t>b$. So, a minus sign is necessary in the formula. i edited correspondingly.

without piecewise functions one must be quite careful that the functions involved satisfy all necessary conditions to fit only one expresssion.

Comment: I do not have strict requirements for fixing the maximum, therefore, your solution suits me completely. But if a correction is required, I will take into account your remark.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
f(a) & x \le 0 \\
f(\frac{b-a}{b}x + a) & 0 \le x \le b\\
f(b) & x \ge b
\end{cases}
$$
and you've got the function that the text under the right-hand graph indicates, although not what the *picture* in the right-hand graph indicates.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Let's try to reformulate. We need to take the desired piece of the function (on the selected interval) and transform it as if it changes over time. Those. the selected piece must be reflected about the y-axis.

Comment: I agree that's what the PICTURE shows; what the text below the picture says is exactly the opposite. Only...I now realize it doesn't. You've chosen to label $f(a)$ with the name $y_b$, and vice-versa! I never imagined anyone would deliberately do that, so...more fool me. I shall live in shame forever. But I totally understand -- you were in a hurry, which justifies wasting others' time.

Comment: I ask you to forgive me for the mistakes in the question. By the way, I corrected your method a little and it works.